# Position background image according to other resizing html elements

Tags: javascript, html, resize, background-image, css-position

So I have a `div` that is positioned in the middle of my page(centered horizontally but not vertically), and it scales to fit the device width until the device becomes larger than 600px. After that the `div` remains at 600px wide and stays centered in the window no matter how much larger it becomes.

What I would like to do is position a background image so that it is always located at the bottom left of this scaling `div` (background of the page not background of the `div`). I believe I will need to use javascript to do this, but I'm not exactly sure. I think I might need to do something like:

```
var divWidth = document.getElementById('theScalingDiv').offsetWidth;
var pageWidth = document.clientWidth;
var xCoord = (pageWidth/2) - (divWidth/2);
```

Then I could use absolute positioning to position the background image according to the height of the scaling `div` and the calculated `xCoord`. Does this sound like it would work?

Answer (score 0):

You could use fixed positioning on the div:

```
.divtoposition {
position:fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7v5L4/

Comment: I know I could use fixed positioning, but I don't really want to for aesthetic purposes. I want it to be always centered.

Comment: Ok, does the background image need to scale too? If not, it could be done with absolute positioning. . . http://jsfiddle.net/7v5L4/6/